# loss of significance errors in mathematical expressions

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Find a way of computing

$$f(x) = \dfrac{e^{3x} - \cos (2x)}{3x}$$

without serious loss of significance near $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be Taylor series $$f(x) = \dfrac{e^{3x} - \cos (2x)}{3x}=1+\frac{13 x}{6}+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{65 x^3}{72}+\frac{27 x^4}{40}+\frac{793
   x^5}{2160}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Running a small Fortran program in double precision (machine accuracy being $\epsilon=1.084 \times 10^{-19}$,$\epsilon$ being the smallest value such that $1+\epsilon>1$), the loss of accuracy seems to start very early (around $x=10^{-7}$).

For $x=10^{-12}$, the expansion gave a value equal to $1.00000000000216671$ while an unlimited precision calculation gave                  $1.00000000000216667$.

It seems that the series work very well down to $x=10^{-15}$ with my program.

**Added later**

Using a CAS, I looked for the root $x_n$ of $$\dfrac{e^{3x} - \cos (2x)}{3x}=1+10^{-n}$$ What I found is interesting since $x_7=4.61308\times10^{-8}$,$x_8=3.16911\times 10^{-9}$ but $x_9=-1.37633\times 10^{-9}$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: how do we actual get this i am using the taylor series but not able to get the answer ...any further explanation .

Comment: Write the Taylor series for $e^y$ in which you replace later $y$ by $3x$; write the Taylor series for $\cos(z)$ in which you replace later $z$ by $2x$; substract and divide the result by $3x$.